# What's wrong with For Loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
package mygradeloops;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyGradeLoops {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char x = 'A';

        for (x='0';x<'9';x++){

        System.out.println("Please enter in one of your grades.");

        System.in.read();

        System.out.println("Keep going!");


        }   
    }   
}
```

This code keeps double printing after the first "grade". Does anyone know why it double prints? Have I done the "For Loop" wrong?

Comment: Double-printing what?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Can you provide a sample output of your program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's "double printing" because when you enter a character by pressing return, you're actually writing two characters: the character you typed, and `\n` (newline character).

Add a second `System.in.read();` call to read the newline character:

```
for (x='0';x<'9';x++){
    System.out.println("Please enter in one of your grades.");

    System.in.read(); // your character
    System.in.read(); // newline

    System.out.println("Keep going!");
}
```

Also, initializing `x` to `'A'` in not needed, `char x;` is fine. In fact, it doesn't make sense to use a `char` in this loop, using an `int` would be preferred.

Comment: This actually answered my question, and helped the program. Thanks a lot, and thanks to everyone who could answer! I apologize for not being able to be more clear, it's my first time on here.

Answer (score 0):

The `read` method for `System.in` (an `InputStream`) only reads one byte of data from the input stream.  Because you must hit "Enter" to send your input to the stream, you have two characters on the stream - the character you typed plus a newline.

The `for` loop loops twice, and "double prints" `Keep going!` and `Please enter in one of your grades.` because each iteration reads one of the two characters on the stream.

It would be easier to wrap `System.in` in a `InputStreamReader` then a `BufferedReader` or just initialize a `Scanner` with `System.in`.  With a `BufferedReader` you can just call `readLine()`, and with a `Scanner` you can call `nextLine()`.

Also, it's unclear why you are looping from `'0'` to `'9'` with `char`s.  It would be clearer to use an `int` for `a` and loop from `0` until `9`.